# How to avoid duplicate records using insert in the PL/SQL block as after running the block 2-3 time after that it starts giving constraint error?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

After running the block more than 2 times that block or inside that block one functions gives the constraint error because of duplicate inseration how to avoid the duplicate insert into the function? or query so that manually i don't need to write delete query separetly need to add one more query that avoid the duplicate insertation.

This is the query  inside the block in one function.

```
insert into igm.fcdrft(
    T, 
    G, 
    L
    STARTDATE,
    D ,
    TYPE , 
    F,  
    Q ,
    M,
    DAYS
    )
select f.T, 
    f.G, 
    f.L,
    u.startDate,
    f.D ,
    f.TYPE ,
    f.F,
    f.Q,
    f.M,    
    u.DAYS
from igm.TEMP  f 
LEFT join igm.part u  
on u.ACT_STARTD=f.startdate
where f.type in ('2','3') 
and u.startdate between '01-09-2023' and '13-01-2025';
```

Comment: Is there any *unique identifier* among your fields?

Comment: these are the primary keys  T, 
    G, 
    L
    STARTDATE,
    TYPE , 
    Q ,
    M,

Comment: Compound or single keys?

Comment: You may look into [`IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPKEY_INDEX`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#CHDEGDDG).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the primary key?

```sql
Alter table  igm.fcdrft add constraint fcdrft_pk primary key(...)
```

Then

```sql
insert into igm.fcdrft (...)
select ... log errors into igm.fcdrft_err reject limit nolimit
```

See https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_JNEICX6W0LNOA88CQIXO9A22A.html

Although, it would be much better for performance just to `insert select` without log errors and make sure that the select does not return rows that violate the primary key for that table.
You may as well `insert select ... where not exists (...)` to make sure that you will not violate the PK.
Or you may `merge` instead of `insert`, depending on what the business requirements are.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` to avoid insertion of already existed records in `igm.fcdrft` :

```
insert into igm.fcdrft(
    T, 
    G, 
    L
    STARTDATE,
    D ,
    TYPE , 
    F,  
    Q ,
    M,
    DAYS
    )
select f.T, 
    f.G, 
    f.L,
    u.startDate,
    f.D ,
    f.TYPE ,
    f.F,
    f.Q,
    f.M,    
    u.DAYS
from igm.TEMP  f 
LEFT join igm.part u  
on u.ACT_STARTD=f.startdate
where f.type in ('2','3') 
and u.startdate between '01-09-2023' and '13-01-2025'
and not exists
(
    select null from igm.fcdrft where igm.fcdrft.T=f.T and igm.fcdrft.G=f.G and igm.fcdrft.STARTDATE=u.startDate, igm.fcdrft.Q=f.Q and igm.fcdrft.M=f.M
)
```